# Update MYSQL no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo este código:

```html
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])){ header("Location: index.php");}
include("db_files/db.php");
include("inc/functions.php");
$oldpass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['oldpass']);
$oldcrypt = encripta_password(mysqli_real_escape_string ($db, $oldpass));

$newpass = encripta_password(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['newpass']));
$renewpass = encripta_password(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['renewpass']));

$usermail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_SESSION['user']);

$strSQL = "SELECT password FROM usuarios WHERE email = '".$usermail."'";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
if ($result['password'] == $oldcrypt){
 if ($newpass == $renewpass){
  $strSQL = "UPDATE usuarios SET usuarios.password = '".$newpass."' WHERE usuarios.email = '".$usermail."'";
  $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
  if ($db->query($query) === TRUE) {
   echo "Updated";
  }else{
   echo "Not updated". $db->error."<br>";
  }
 }
}else{
 echo "No match password";
}
// $pass = encripta_password("asdasd");
// echo $pass;
?>
```

Y al ejecutarlo, me da este error:

> Not updatedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1' at line 1

Este mismo update en el phpmyadmin funciona correctamente (sustituyendo las variables por su valor)

Añado que si que hace el update pero no sé de dónde viene ese error.

Esta es la funcion encripta_password:

```
 function encripta_password($password)
{
    //$salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    $saltedPW =  $password . PANDAERP_HASH;
    $hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);
    return $hashedPW;
}
define("PANDAERP_HASH", "16a507d6f3da37d8ba00b28bf622d144cba96f65d3a18f8b15911697d6409f0f");
```

Comment: La sentencia parece correcta a primera vista, puede que sea algo relacionado con los valores de las variables. ¿Podrías compartir la sentencia SQL generada?¿alguno de los valores contiene comillas de algún tipo?

Comment: no sé si es esto a lo que te referias:   UPDATE usuarios SET usuarios.password = 'eb36a4c5083982eeff5d022770d5aa8ddc8e2651fb12bed620e7d8be0b30db29' WHERE usuarios.email = 'pavlobod91@gmail.com'

Comment: @PavloB. ¿Has detectado que haya alguna sentencia que no te funcione?

Comment: Copiando la cadena que has puesto en Notepad++ veo que hay caracteres raros entre b3 y 0d. ¿Qué es lo que hace `encripta_password`?

Comment: Prueba modificando tu SQL de manera que la clave y email queden entre comillas dobles, asi:  UPDATE usuarios SET usuarios.password = "eb36a4c5083982eeff5d022770d5aa8ddc8e2651fb12bed620e7d8be0b3‌​0db29" WHERE usuarios.email = "pavlobod91@gmail.com"

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro me ha entrado curiosidad con tu comentario. ¿A que te refieres con caracteres raros?

Comment: He copiado lo que has puesto en un [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5deahkm/), si te fijas, aparecen dos caracteres en rojo que seguramente no deberían estar ahí.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Nunca había visto que aparecieran caracteres así. Muy curioso. Gracias por compartirlo :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu error está en que intentas ejecutar el query dos veces, te explico en comentarios:

```
        //esto ejecuta el query una vez y devuelve 1 (éxito)            
        $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
        //esto intenta ejecutar el 1 como query nuevamente.
        if ($db->query($query) === TRUE) {
```

Deja solo el primero, o cambia el segundo pasándole la cadena que contiene tu sentencia SQL.

Comment: Efectivamente, era eso, he sustituido el $query del if por $strSQL y ahora no da ningún error.